# How to pass experimental_allow_proto3_optional for C# <proto/> definitions to enable optional in proto3?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've looked everywhere for this. The C# grpc people don't know how to do it, and point to the grpc/grpc people for the tooling but you're not allowed to ask questions there.  I guess I could phrase this as a feature but that feels like cheating. (please add documentation too show how...)

How does one pass the parameter for this to C# grpc in the <proto> definition so that we can use the optional keyword?

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to check the source of the tooling - I can't see any particular mention of custom options, though. Side note: the protobuf-net tooling ("protogen") implements this feature by default :)

Comment: I've looked and there is a GrpcOutputOptions but I can't find any permutation or combination that makes it work.

Comment: BTW, I'm very seriously looking at protobuf-net tooling, but I need flutter clients and the proto generation code isn't stable as of yet so genning the flutter client is iffy. If it was more stable and linked into Swagger-GRPC I'd be there completely.

Comment: out of curiosity, what features do you mean by "more stable" and "linked into Swagger-GRPC"? What is the gap there? Asking so I can think about roadmap.

Comment: More stable in that it works trivially with the .net ecosystem and I’d be using it right now if .net was really viable for anything end user anymore. Basically I need to be able to point protoc at an endpoint of some sort and gen dart or JavaScript etc. that use case needs examples and clear messaging without anything manual. As soon as that’s solid I’m there in a heartbeat.

Comment: Also swagger grpc allows the same as openapi/swagger rest with self documented and usable ui to share with 3rd parties. With grpc it uses grpc-web. James Newton king has a demo of some of it as part of the grpc-rest poc.

Comment: we implemented the reflection gRPC API recently, which means services that query running services: work just fine - and .proto schema generation from services. Totally hear you, though.

Comment: Ya I’m super excited about that. It’s still a little rough. And I’d like to make sure that it basically gens endpoints under say /protos as basic http gets that protoc can use. Then I don’t have to manually gen the protos and then manually use protoc (which itself is really really bad). Would be nice to have an extension method on endpoint routing that just created it all automatically in a way protoc can use and genned swagger with a link in the ui to the protoc command that would gen a client for you from it. That’s my perfect world.

Comment: @JamesHancock Did you figure it out?

Comment: @PascalBourque As of right now there's no way to pass these parameters in your csproj file. You can in theory run the awful protoc tool and make it work but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

As for January 2021, the only - yet hacky - way around this is to make your proto filename (or a directory name) contain the string `test_proto3_optional`, as pointed out by [protobuf documentation](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md#satisfying-the-experimental-check):

> If you try to run protoc on a file with proto3 optional fields, you will get an error because the feature is still experimental. [...] There are two options for getting around this error:
>
> 1. Pass `--experimental_allow_proto3_optional` to protoc.
> 2. *Make your filename (or a directory name) contain the string `test_proto3_optional`. This indicates that the proto file is specifically for testing proto3 optional support, so the check is suppressed.*

For more information see [#977](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/977) (grpc-dotnet), [#19164](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19164) (AspNetCore.Docs) and [#23686](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23686) (grpc) issues.

Comment: Yuk.  Passing these parameters needs to be part of the support for grpc in .net